# i need make use of environment inside main class annotated with @springbootapplication

Tags: spring-boot

I tried using autowired of environement variable in main method of spring bootapplication and am trying to get value from application.properties and assign it to astring variable in the main method class. when i print and check the environment object , it prints null and ends up with nullpointer exception

```
public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getData(){
        System.out.println(env);
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("app.name"));
        return env.getProperty("app.name");
    }
    private  String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        System.out.println("name is "+new App().getData());
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    }
}                                                                           
***in application.properties***                        

    app.name=aravind
    app.city=mumbai~

    Am getting null pointerexception if i call getProperty method, also env object is printing null
```

Comment: can you add full error log in your question ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.batch.demo.ui.App.getData(App.java:15)
 at com.batch.demo.ui.App.main(App.java:28)
This isthe maximum error am getting

Comment: where is your application.properties placed ?

Comment: its available in resource folder

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that this is against the property flow of the application because it would allow for injecting environment variables before system variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are Autowiring inside Main class. I don't think that will work for you.

for more details see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059266/spring-autowire-inside-of-springbootapplication-class-is-behaving-differently-be ]

what you can do is create other class then mark it as `@Component` then retrieve Environment data.

Example

```
@Component
public class TestClass{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
        
    @Autowired
    TestClass(Environment env) { //this is constructor
        System.out.println("App Name: "+getData());
    }

    public String getData(){
        System.out.println(env);
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("app.name"));
        return env.getProperty("app.name");
    }
}
```

also add `@ComponentScan("yourpackagename")` after `@SpringBootApplication` in Main class

Comment: Hi Arun, is there any specific reason like in main class it wont happen. I need to understand that part. what you said i have already tried. Thats fine.

Comment: Spring-Boot autowires an object only if it is under Component Class. Since adding @springbootapplication it will mark Main class as entry point to the Application and not Main as a Component.

Comment: And... how to initialize `TestClass`? with `@Autowired`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Environment environment = SpringApplication.run(YourServer.class, args).getEnvironment();
    String value = environment.getProperty("your.application.property");
}
```